# Use which tense to ask someone to check the status of someting?

Tags: tense

Suppose I would borrow a Kindle from my brother, and I want to check the status of the Kindle to see if it has been broken or not, and want to use the word "work", which should I say?

> *1. Is your kindle still working?*
>
> *2. Does your kindle still work?*

Comment: Both examples are fine.

Comment: @LittleEva Then which is more natural? I doubt the first sentence would cause a misunderstanding that the Kindle was turned on and I was checking the uptime...

Comment: As far as I can tell both examples are equally fine. No problems with either. What do you think is wrong or awkward about them?

Comment: Yes, **Robusto has the sense of it**. If the Kindle was on you would say to your brother, "Is it still working." If your brother has finished using the device and put it away, you could then ask, "Does the Kindle still work."

Answer (score 1):

In that case we would normally use the progressive (continuous) form: *Is your Kindle still working?*